# Checking JS object types with TypeScript - Cannot find name 'key'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am very new to TypeScript. I am using it to check types in a JavaScript file with comments.

I have an object with values to be arrays of number, and the keys can be any string. I declare it like so

```js
/**
 * @type { [key: string]: number[] }
 */
let myObj = {};
```

With this, I get the following error `Cannot find name 'key'`.

What might I be doing wrong here? How should I declare the type?

Comment: @NarenMurali I thought the `@type` comment does exactly that?

Comment: check this stackblitz, it works fine [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgvzom?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why my original syntax doesn't work, but the following seems to:

```js
/**
 * @type  {Object.<string, number[]}
 */
let myObj = {};
```